# IF function where the first result returns #VALUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got the following in Column A:

```
112234
113456(Producer)
123211
114523(Producer)
224431(Producer)
```

I want to create a Column B and a Column C that separates this out to:

```
112234
113456         (Producer)
123211
114523         (Producer)
224431         (Producer)
```

So I put this IF statement in Column B, but it gives me a #VALUE for the 1st and 3rd records:

```
=IF(FIND("(",A2)>1,LEFT(A2,FIND("(",A2)-1),A2)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately they're not.  Usually between 3 and 7, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FIND()` returns an error when what you are looking for isn't found, not 0.

Try this instead.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("(",A2)),A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("(",A2)-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the numbers always 6 digits? If so, I think nothing would stop you from just using text-to-columns.

The current error is the result of `FIND()` not actually returning any number to compare in your `IF()`. You could bypass this by a simple concatenation to assert an opening paranthesis does exist:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1&"(")-1)
```

---

Btw, I'm not sure if the data after the opening paranthesis would always be "Producer", but just in case it isn't you could use the following in `C1`:

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,LEN(B1),"")
```